# Chartjs Bar Chart showing old data when hovering when use of ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm new to javascript

I have a bar chart that's created using chart.js. Everything works fine on page load, but when I change value, a glitch appears. The new data is brought in, but when I hover over it, the old data is shown.

```
 $('#fanbase-overtime-platform').on("change", function() {

$('.global-page-filter-loader').show();
var platform = $(this).val();
var selected_artist = $('#artist-select-list').val();
var requestSimilarArtist = $.ajax({
  url: "{{url('label/artist/compare/overtime/follower')}}",
  method: "POST",
  data: {_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), selected_artist: selected_artist, platform: platform}
});
requestSimilarArtist.done(function( resp ) {
  if(!resp.error) {
    if(resp.result != undefined) {
      var dateArr = [];
      var followerArr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < resp.result.artists.length; i++) {
        followerArr[i] = [];
        $.each(resp.result.followers[i], function(index, item) {
          if(i == 0) {
            dateArr.push(item.last_date);
          }
          followerArr[i].push(item.follower_value);
        });
      }
      var ctx = $("#fanbase-overtime-line-chart");
      var chartOptions = {
       responsive: true,
       maintainAspectRatio: false,
       legend: {
          position: "bottom"
       },
       hover: {
          mode: "label"
       },
       scales: {
          xAxes: [
             {
                display: true,
                gridLines: {
                   color: "#f3f3f3",
                   drawTicks: false
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                   display: true,
                   labelString: "Month"
                }
             }
          ],
          yAxes: [
             {
                display: true,
                gridLines: {
                   color: "#f3f3f3",
                   drawTicks: false
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                   display: true,
                   labelString: "Value"
                }
             }
          ]
       },
       title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Line Chart - Legend"
       }
      };

      var colors = [
        {
          borderColor: "#e91e63",
          pointBorderColor: "#e91e63"
        },
        {
          borderColor: "#00CCFF",
          pointBorderColor: "#00CCFF"
        },
        {
          borderColor: "#ffc107",
          pointBorderColor: "#ffc107"
        }
      ]
      var arrOfChartData = []
      $.each(resp.result.artists, function(index, item) {
        arrOfChartData.push({
          label: item.name,
          data: followerArr[index],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: colors[index].borderColor,
          pointBorderColor: colors[index].pointBorderColor,
          pointBackgroundColor: "#FFF",
          pointBorderWidth: 2,
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
          pointRadius: 4
        });
      });

      var chartData = {
        labels: dateArr,
        datasets: arrOfChartData
      };
      var config = {
         type: "line",
         options: chartOptions,
         data: chartData
      };
      var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
      lineChart.update();

    }
  }
  $('.global-page-filter-loader').hide();
});


 });
```

What is the best way to destroy the original data so that when I change the date range and hover over the new chart ?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar experience. so i am using this way which is destroying previous chart before draw new one.
my code down below

```
var canvasContainer = canvasItem.parent();
var canvasHtml = '<canvas id="'+canvasItem.attr('id')+'"><canvas>';
canvasItem.remove();
$(canvasContainer).append(canvasHtml);
```

...wirte your chart options like

```
var options = {
    title:{},
    scalses:{}
}
```

after you write the options you wanna use in your chart
then

```
var ctx = document.getElementById(canvasItem.attr('id')).getContext('2d');
var Chart = new window.Chart(ctx, {
        data:{
        labels:chartdata.date,
        datasets:chartdata.datasets,
        },
        options : options
});
```

it works fine with me

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me Change the chart to global by making it window (Change the declaration) Like `var lineChart` To `window.lineChart`

For Destroy Chart before Declaire

```
       if (window.lineChart){

             window.lineChart.destroy();  

           }
      window.lineChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Hope Help

Comment: Its Working Thank You